# Adding and removing multiple filters in Knockout JS

Tags: jquery, sorting, knockout.js

I'd like for my users to not only be able to use multiple filters, but to click an active filter to remove it. Right now, filters only work one at a time and there is no way to remove a filter other than clicking "show all". I'm fairly sure the answer is to use a ko.observableArray to store the filters, add or remove them as appropriate, and loop through them with filteredPeople. Unfortunately, my attempts at this solution did not work as planned, so I'm turning towards SO for help.

Here is a JSFiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/rrahlf/EZUEF/6/

And this is my Knockout code:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        {firstName:'James',lastName:'Smith',age:38},
        {firstName:'Susan',lastName:'Smith',age:36},
        {firstName:'Jeremy',lastName:'Smith',age:10},
        {firstName:'Megan',lastName:'Smith',age:7},
        {firstName:'James',lastName:'Jones',age:40},
        {firstName:'Martha',lastName:'Jones',age:36},
        {firstName:'Peggy',lastName:'Jones',age:10}
    ]);

    self.headers = [
        {title:'First Name',sortPropertyName:'firstName', asc: true, active: false},
        {title:'Last Name',sortPropertyName:'lastName', asc: true, active: false},
        {title:'Age',sortPropertyName:'age', asc: true, active: false}
    ];
    self.filters = [
        {title:'Show All', filter: null},
        {title:'Only Smith', filter: function(item){return item.lastName == 'Smith';}},
        {title:'Only Jones', filter: function(item){return item.lastName == 'Jones';}},
        {title:'Only Adults', filter: function(item){return item.age >= 18; }}
    ];

    self.activeSort = ko.observable(function(){return 0;}); //set the default sort
    self.sort = function(header, event){
        //if this header was just clicked a second time
        if(header.active) {
            header.asc = !header.asc; //toggle the direction of the sort
        }
        //make sure all other headers are set to inactive
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.headers, function(item){ item.active = false; } );
        //the header that was just clicked is now active
        header.active = true;//our now-active header

        var prop = header.sortPropertyName;
        var ascSort = function(a,b){ return a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : 0; };
        var descSort = function(a,b){ return a[prop] > b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : 0; };
        var sortFunc = header.asc ? ascSort : descSort;

        //store the new active sort function
        self.activeSort(sortFunc);
    };

    self.activeFilter = ko.observable(self.filters[0].filter);//set a default filter    
    self.setActiveFilter = function(model,event){
        self.activeFilter(model.filter);
    };

    self.filteredPeople = ko.computed(function(){
        var result;
        if(self.activeFilter()){
            result = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.people(), self.activeFilter());
        } else {
            result = self.people();
        }
        return result.sort(self.activeSort());
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: filters">
<input type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.setActiveFilter, value: title"/>
</div>

<br/>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: headers">
        <th data-bind="click: $parent.sort, text: title"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the current filter in `setActiveFilter` function, and drop it, if user click's on the same filter button twice:

```
self.setActiveFilter = function(model) {
    if (self.activeFilter() != model.filter) {
        self.activeFilter(model.filter);
    } else {
        self.activeFilter(self.filters[0].filter);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EZUEF/175/)

Comment: Clever! That solves that problem, but there's still the issue of multiple filters... is there a way to show, for example, adults with the last name of Smith?

Comment: I can sugest you to add `isSelected: ko.observable()` prop in each of items in `self.filters`. Remove `self.activeFilter`, and use only `self.filters` and `isSelected` prop in `self.filteredPeople`.

Comment: Good idea - that helps remove some of the clutter in the code as well. Accepted.