# Applying multiple filters using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been following this tutorial:
http://ryanrahlf.com/filtering-table-data-with-knockout-js/ 
and I was wondering if there was a way to apply multiple filters. I'm new to web design in general and don't have my feet under me when it comes to knockout or javascript. I found another question similar to this and it has a suggested solution, but no working code example. Once I get to the filteredPeople computed, I've been struggling to get it to work, so I've left it alone for this question.

```
self.filters = [
    {title:'Show All', filter: null, isSelected: ko.observable(false)},
    {title:'Only Smith', filter: function(item){return item.lastName == 'Smith';}, isSelected: ko.observable(false)},
    {title:'Only Jones', filter: function(item){return item.lastName == 'Jones';}, isSelected: ko.observable(false)},
    {title:'Only Adults', filter: function(item){return item.age >= 18; }}
    ];
self.filteredPeople = ko.computed(function(){
    var result;
    if(self.activeFilter()){
        result = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.people(), self.activeFilter());
    }
    else{
        result = self.people;
    }
    return result.sort(self.activeSort());
 }
```

So what I'm asking is how I can I change self.filteredPeople to auto-update and chain filters together based on the .isSelected() property in the filters array? I want to remove the .activeFilter() and .setActiveFilter() methods and use the isSelected observable.

Similar question with a sort of answer:
[Adding and removing multiple filters in Knockout JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049643/adding-and-removing-multiple-filters-in-knockout-js)

my JSFiddle with full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/L4Lsm/

Answer (score 0):

if you just loop through all of your filters to determine which has isSelected set to true in your filteredPeople computed it should automatically be updated once one of the isSelected observables changes on any of the filters in the self.filters array. Also if you will have an ability to add a filter you will want to define self.filters as an observableArray itself.

Comment: I did try having it setup as a ko.utils.arrayForEach and pass in the self.people() and then check for isSelected(true) then run the filter, however, trying to loop, compare and see if the record is already in there such as Jones plus adults would net me Martha, Peggy and James and for adults Peggy and James. This would result with an array of Martha, Peggy, James, Peggy, James if I just pushed them as they returned true.

Comment: You will have to maintain the collection result people yourself, because you might receive same people objects from different active filters, you will have to manually make sure that they are not duplicated. if you will define a result array in your filteredPeople  computable, I think simple indexOf on the array will suffice to check if person was already added.

Comment: That's a much better solution. I was trying to set flags, and use multiple arrays and nested for loops and compare and push and pop. I'll try this and update my Fiddle. Thanks for the idea. I'll report back with results.

Comment: I lied. No updated JSFiddle. I'm embarrassed that even with 9 if statements and a ridiculous amount of conditionals, it still doesn't work.